# Python CSV : field containing quotation mark at the beginning

Tags: python, csv, quotation-marks

I am trying to read a CSV file containing a line like following:

```
test,"test,"test,test,test,test
```

There is a problem with the quotation marks (There are six fields, but they are retrieved as five fields, as "test,"test is read as a single field).

I have tried modifying the entry as follows, but I still can't retrieve the quotation mark:

```
test,""test,""test,test,test,test  # quotation marks disappear when the entry is read.

test,\"test,\"test,test,test,test  # backslashes are also retrieved; escaping doesn't seem to work.
```

I'm reading CSV file this way:

```
info_source = csv.reader(open('.info.csv'), skipinitialspace=True)

for row in ling_info_source:
    data = row[1].strip()
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `"` is the [quoting character](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) of Python's `csv` module.  Use

```
csv.reader(open('.info.csv'), skipinitialspace=True, quotechar=None)
```

to disable this default.  The example you gave will result in the record

```
['test', '"test', '"test', 'test', 'test', 'test']
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I can't read cases such as:    [test, "test,  "test,  "commaToRead,commaToRead",  test,   test]. For this case I should read: [test]["test]["test]["commaToRead,commaToRead"][test][test]. Is it possible?

Comment: @David: That's ambiguous.  How is the parser supposed to know which double quotes are meant for quoting and which aren't?

Comment: I thought I should add this because it's something I had to test to clarify: the quoting character only applies if it appears right after the delimiter. That is to say, the quoting character must be the first character in the new delimited section in order to nullify any delimiters within the text.

Comment: i think parser should see that in `"test, "test,` quotation mark is followed by `test` and in `"commaToRead,commaToRead",` quotation mark is followed by comma

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` argument to `reader()`

Comment: While using `quotechar=None` as in my answer works fine, `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` seems to be the documented way to disable quoting in the reader.